# How to scrape the first n paragraphs from a url

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to web-scraping, and I am really having a hard time with extracting some paragraphs from a url. [From the following link](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_863) I'm trying to print all the paragraphs under the **Cover Page** and **Short Summary** headers. But my program is not working.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import requests
import bs4

url = 'http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_863'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all('div',attrs={"mw-content-ltr mw-content-text"})
for x in table:
    if (x.get(id) == "Cover Page"):
        print (x.get('p').get_text())
    elif(x.get(id) == "Short Summary"):
        print (x.get('p').get_text())
```

When I run my program, it does not print anything nor show an error message. Is there any way where I can print only the paragraphs under the **Cover Page** and **Short Summary** section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we analyze the HTML source of the page we can see that we need to get the Cover Page and Short Summary:

- Cover Page -> all "p" tags between h2 Cover Page and h2 short summary
- Short Summary -> all "p" tags between h2 Short Summary and h2 Long
  Summary

On the code, we need to find all h2 and p tags and then find the index of each h2 as our marker. When we got our markers, we then re-loop the tree and be able to get all needed paragraphs between h2 tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import requests
import bs4

url = 'http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_863'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all('div',attrs={"mw-content-ltr mw-content-text"})
for x in table:
    i = 0
    cover_page_mark = 0
    short_summary_mark = 0
    long_summary_mark = 0

    cover_page = ''
    short_summary = ''

    for el in x.find_all(['h2', 'p']):
        if el.name == 'h2':
            if "Cover Page" in el.get_text() and el.name == 'h2':
                cover_page_mark = i
            if "Short Summary" in el.get_text() and el.name == 'h2':
                short_summary_mark = i
            if "Long Summary" in el.get_text() and el.name == 'h2':
                long_summary_mark = i
        i += 1

    i = 0
    for el in x.find_all(['h2', 'p']):
        if el.name == 'p':
            if cover_page_mark < i < short_summary_mark:
                cover_page += el.get_text()
            if short_summary_mark < i < long_summary_mark:
                short_summary += el.get_text()
        i += 1

    print cover_page
    print short_summary
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired result making your script concise you can do something like this as well. Run it and see the magic.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_863").text,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select("#mw-content-text"):
    required_data = [p_item.text.strip() for p_item in item.select("p")][1:4]
    print('\n'.join(required_data))
```

Comment: This is a nice answer. But we should consider its flexibility, what if the site added new <p> tags, then this will return invalid. +1 vote for you :)

Comment: The style I've used here is definitely error prone. However, I've created this script to solve this particular issue. Thanks for the upvote, by the way.